# Why non-captured variable is raising warning?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, lambda

Consider this code in VS**2015**:

```
int a,b;

[]
{
    int a;  //  C4456: declaration of 'a' hides previous local declaration
};
```

Why `a` in lambda giving such warning? It compiles fine in VS2013.

**EDIT:** Interestingly, (and incorrectly), following is not an error in VS2013:

```
 [a]
 {        
     int a; // No error, even if `a` is captured.
     a++;
 };
```

Comment: I'm not sure the latter case should be an error. The former seems like a compiler bug to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first warning definitely looks like a compiler bug.

The second one isn't a bug since you're declaring it in a different scope. The variable is only captured, it is not declared by the capture.

Think about the function object this could generate

```
class foo {
  foo(int a): a(a) {}

  void operator()() {
    int a;
  }

  int a;
};
```

There's no conflict between the two declarations of `a`, and since the lambda compiles to something like this, that's why the capture doesn't care about the inner declaration.

**Update:** This is something completely different from

```
void foo(int a) {
  int a;
}
```

because in the case of the lambda, it will get compiled to a class with an `operator()`, and the captures will get passed in as constructor parameters, which is why they're in a different scope.

Comment: Is `void foo(int a) { float a; }` not a bug, if compiler allows?

Comment: Basically functions are completely different from lambdas. If it is still not clear, please do ask and I'll update the answer with more details :)

Comment: I am understanding it all. Interesting for you also: There is same warning in `operator()` by VS2015 saying it is hiding class member `a`. What I can say is : better warnings.

Comment: @Ajay hmm that's weird, yeah it's probably a VS2015 thing, since I'm not getting any warning with clang

Comment: No direct link available. Go: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/rsscomments.aspx?WeblogPostID=10550854, and search for C4458

Comment: Yes, the warning should not be issued for the first case.  This was first reported to us in July:  [Lambda without captures warn about hiding external declarations](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/933092/lambdas-without-captures-warn-about-hiding-external-declarations).