# Use lambda to avoid variable shadowing

Tags: c++, lambda

There is a member function in my code like this

```
void foo(bool result)
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetAppModuleState());
    //doing something here

    if(result)
    {
        AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetAppModuleState());
        //do something here
    }    
}
```

This give warning in VC compiler `warning C4456: declaration of '_ctlState' hides previous local declaration`. and to avoid this I'm planing to use lambda like this, than creating a new function.

```
void foo(bool result)
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetAppModuleState());
    //doing something here

    if(result)
    {
        [](){AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetAppModuleState())};
        //do something here
    }    
}
```

But it still complain the warning, So I'm thinking does the declarations outside the lambda block is transparent to the inside, by default?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058449/why-non-captured-variable-is-raising-warning

Comment: Why are you calling AFX_MANAGE_STATE twice in case result is true?